# Able to curl a POST request but Python script using requests returns 500 error?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a microservice in Django that takes a postalcode via a POST request and returns a list of nearby postalcodes.

I know the service works because I can curl it

```
curl http://172.17.0.6:80/zipcode/ -d "postalcode=97201"
```

returning

```
{"postalcodes": ["97201", "97239", "97205", "97204", "97228", "97238", "97207", "97269", "97268", "97240", "97250", "97242"]}
```

I am trying to write a script which will become the basis of how my other microservices communicate with this service, the problem is the script is returning a 500 error and I can't quite pin down what I'm doing wrong.

python script:

```
import requests
def calculate_postalcodes(postalcode):
    url="http://172.17.0.6:80/zipcode/"
    params ={'postalcode':postalcode}
    data = requests.post(url=url, params=params)
    # output = data.json()
    # zipcodes = output['postalcodes']
    return data.text


postalcodess = calculate_postalcodes('97201')
print postalcodess
```

django logs

```
mypostalcode = request.POST['postalcode']
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "'postalcode'"
```

Because we know the service works with a curl request, I have chosen not to included code snippets.  I am basically just trying to pass a zipcode through a POST request in an identical way that is happening through my CURL request.

Comment: hmmm. .. is there anyway that you can look at the parameters that the service receives. in flask I can do something like `print(requests.args)` edit: I think `request.POST.keys()` should work

Comment: fixed it,  the issue was using params instead of data is not permitted by my location app.

Answer (score 0):

switching from

```
data = requests.post(url=url, params=params)
```

to

```
data = requests.post(url=url, data=params)
```

fixed the issue.  Passing parameters through URL is not permitted by my webserver and that's what params does (whereas data passes it through the http request)